# Android SocketIO still works in background

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am creating an Android application with [Socket IO](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/#)

But I checked from log, the socket is not disconnected when app go to background, I don't need to use socket when app is in background. So, is it correct? Does it drain battery much when socket still works in background?
If I want to force disconnect socket in background, how can I do it?

Thanks for reading this

Comment: what Android version you are using?